# Redirecting to next page when set redirect = false ?

Tags: apex, visualforce

After clicking a button on a VF page I'm redirecting to a new page but using setRedirect(false), it is working fine but if I use apex:actionStatus to disable the button then it is not working.

Note: both pages uses the same controller.

Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: I am pretty sure there something wrong with reRender sections

Comment: I am using same functionality for another button where setRedirect(true) and uses different controllers there it is working fine, only when setRedirect(false) and both pages uses the same controller it is not working.

Comment: Just for some one with same issue refer this                          https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=087300000007ZuSAAU                     found solution in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for some one with same issue refer this                                                                    https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=087300000007ZuSAAU                     found solution in it.